# What is the difference between parsing, reading and lexing?

Tags: parsing, eval, lex

What exactly is the difference between those 3? Isn't their goal transforming strings into data-structures?

Answer (score 4):

Parsing, or, more formally, syntactic analysis, is the process of analyzing a text, made of a sequence of tokens.

Lexing or lexical analysis is the process of converting a sequence of characters into a sequence of tokens.

Reading is the process to acquire data from a source and place it into their volatile memory for processing.

Comment: So reading = lexing . parsing ?

Comment: If you mean "reading" in the Lisp reader sense, then no, reading != lexing . parsing. Lexing converts a sequence of chars to a sequence of tokens. Parsing converts a sequence of tokens to a tree. Reading is a type of parsing where you return data objects instead of abstract syntax trees.